# Why [table].[column] != null is not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, isnull

Why `select * from [table] where [table].[column] != null` is not working for my query and result is empty.

But `select * from [table] where [table].[column] is not null` is working and find records that `[table].[column]` is fill with `null`!

What is the difference between `!= null` and `is not null` in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: `is not null` return records **fill with `null`**? `is not null` is standard, and you cannot compare `null` with `!=`

Comment: You can't compare to something that is not a value. NULL stands for the absence of a value. You can't compare something with nothing. The `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` stands for `has a value` or `does not have a value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` in a database is not a value. It means something like "unknown" or "data missing".

You cannot tell if something where you don't have any information about is equal to something else where you also don't have any information about (`=`, `!=` operators). But you can say whether there is any information available (`IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`).

IMHO, in practice it is not very useful. But it is how it is and has a long history.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare with NULL using `=` operator because NULL means **unknown** value and so you cannot equate something to some unknown value. That is why `IS NULL` clause is provided to filter out rows having column as `null`.

Read more about [**THREE VALUED LOGIC**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/) in SQL Server.